# An inequality in Hölder space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to prove this statement:

> There exists a constant $c$ such that for every $\rho>0$ and any function $v\in C^{1,\alpha}(B(0,\rho))$
>   \begin{equation}
> \|v\|_{C^1(B(0,\rho))}\le |Dv|_{C^{\alpha}(B(0,\rho))} + c\|v\|_{L^2(B(0,\rho))}
> \end{equation}

I think I can use contradiction argument. Assume that for very $n\in N$, there is an $\rho_n>0$ and a $u_n\in B(0,\rho_n)$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\|v_n\|_{C^1(B(0,\rho_n))}> |Dv|_{C^{\alpha}(B(0,\rho_n))} + n\|v\|_{L^2(B(0,\rho_n))}
\end{equation}
Then I can normalize to assume that $\|v_n\|_{C^1(B(0,\rho_n))}=1$. Then I try to use Azela-Ascolli to derive a contradiction. However I can not control the radius $\rho_n$.

Can anyone please help me ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Which norms are you using? With the standard norms, $\lVert v\rVert_{L^2(B(0,\rho))}$ would be proporptional to $\rho^k$ for a constant $v$, and thus the right hand side would tend to $0$ while the left remains constant.

Comment: The $||.||_{C^1}$ is the standard norm in $C^1$. The $|.|_{C^{\alpha}}$ is the $C^{\alpha}$-seminorm. The $||.||_{L^2}$ is the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: In that case, look at $v \equiv 1$, the assertion becomes $1 \leqslant c \cdot \lambda(B(0,\rho))$, and that can't hold for all $\rho > 0$. If you divide by the volume of the ball, it may be true (it probably is, then).

Comment: If the difference between $||a||$ and $\|a\|$ is not conspicuous enough for you, consider the difference between $||a|| ||b||$ and $\|a\|\|b\|$. The former is coded as ||a|| ||b|| and the latter as \|a\|\|b\|. That why the latter is standard usage.

Comment: I read that statement in the book "Partial Differential equations" by Jurgen Jost, Chapter 11, Lemma 11.1.2